# Behaviour of view as Soft Keyboard Appaer not same for all the device?

Tags: android, android-layout, view

i have made app which supported multiple screen means i have added permission of screen size and my app works fine for resolution 320*480 i have tested it in sony xperia,samsung duas,lg optimus all things work fine but in 800*480 size emulator and i have tested in Galaxy S2 for this resolution my view is not looking as it was in other device see the snap as shown below where in last after **Add More Detail**

[image] By clicking add more detail i show six edittext but in first one emulator of size 800*480 when try to type in **lable1** or **detail** as seen soft keyboard open but edittext not comes push up above the soft keyboard so if i scroll that view than it shows where  for 320*480 resolution it push up on the keyboard and no need to scroll.

And for the **Label3** and **detail** for 800*480 resolution it niether show edittext above the soft keyboard nor also able to see by scrolling as for lable1 while in 320*480 resolution it works fine and one more thing i have given  **android:imeOptions="actionNext"** and **android:nextFocusDown="@+id/etMoreDetail3"** for this six edittext but in galaxy s2 it's behaviour changes not works as in other device works in sequence **lable1-->detail1-->lable2-->detail2-->lable3-->detail3**

I have tried by adding in menifest for activity either  **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** ,**adjustResize**, **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"** ,**stateHidden** but no luck nothing change in the output my xml file is at [xml file](http://pastebin.com/86g3qGrv) and i have added this in menifest

```
   <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create different layout for different screen

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/index.html